# cucumber and using alternates when one has a white space

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I'm having a problem here with below code.

The problem is that it is always matching with 'is' even when 'is not' is present.

Can anyone help?

---

#### Feature level

```
Then I take an argument arg1 and match one of these is not when available
```

#### Step definition level

```
Then /^I take an argument (.+) and match one of these (is not|IS|IS NOT|is) when available$/ do |pram1,pram2|

# do stuff...

end
```

Answer (score -1):

I've run the regex and it works for me - returning "is not" as a match.

I've also made it case insensitive(?i) to dry it out

```
irb> "I take an argument arg1 and match one of these is not when available" =~ /^I take an argument (.+) and match one of these (?i)(IS|IS NOT) when available$/

irb> Regexp.last_match.captures
[
[0] "arg1",
[1] "is not"
]
```